# MySQL performance optimization: order by datetime field

Tags: mysql, performance, select

I have a table with roughly 100.000 blog postings, linked to a table with 50 feeds via an 1:n relationship. When I query both tables with a select statement, ordered by a datetime field of the postings table, MySQL always uses filesort, resulting in very slow query times (>1 second). Here's the schema of the `postings` table (simplified):

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| feed_id             | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| crawl_date          | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active           | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| link                | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| author              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title               | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| excerpt             | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| long_excerpt        | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_offtopic_count | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And here's the `feed` table:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type        | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| title       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| website     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| url         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And here's the query that takes >1 second to execute. Please note that the `post_date` field has an index, but MySQL isn't using it to sort the postings table:

```
SELECT 
    `postings`.`id`, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(postings.post_date) as post_date, 
    `postings`.`link`, 
    `postings`.`title`, 
    `postings`.`author`, 
    `postings`.`excerpt`, 
    `postings`.`long_excerpt`, 
    `feeds`.`title` AS feed_title, 
    `feeds`.`website` AS feed_website
FROM 
    (`postings`)
JOIN 
    `feeds` 
ON 
    `feeds`.`id` = `postings`.`feed_id`
WHERE 
    `feeds`.`type` = 1 AND 
    `postings`.`user_offtopic_count` < 10 AND 
    `postings`.`is_active` = 1
ORDER BY 
    `postings`.`post_date` desc
LIMIT 
    15
```

The result of the `explain extended` command on this query shows that MySQL is using filesort:

```
+----+-------------+----------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys                         | key       | key_len | ref                      | rows  | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | postings | ref    | feed_id,is_active,user_offtopic_count | is_active | 1       | const                    | 30996 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | feeds    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type                          | PRIMARY   | 4       | feedian.postings.feed_id |     1 | Using where                 |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+---------------------------------------+-----------+---------+--------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
```

When I remove the `order by` part, MySQL stops using filesort. Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to optimize this query to get MySQL to sort and select the data by using indexes. I have already tried a few things such as creating a combined index on all where/order by fields, as suggested by a few blog postings, but this didn't work either.

Comment: I really like the clear and detailed way you asked this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Create a composite index either on `postings (is_active, post_date)` (in that order).

It will be used both for filtering on `is_active` and ordering by `post_date`.

`MySQL` should show `REF` access method over this index in `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`.

Note that you have a `RANGE` filtering condition over `user_offtopic_count`, that's why you cannot use an index over this field both in filtering and in sorting by other field.

Depending on how selective is your `user_offtopic_count` (i. e. how many rows satisfy `user_offtopic_count < 10`), it may be more useful to create an index on `user_offtopic_count` and let the post_dates be sorted.

To do this, create a composite index on `postings (is_active, user_offtopic_count)` and make sure the `RANGE` access method over this index is used.

Which index will be faster depends on your data distribuion. Create both indexes, `FORCE` them and see which is faster:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_active_offtopic ON postings (is_active, user_offtopic_count);
CREATE INDEX ix_active_date ON postings (is_active, post_date);

SELECT 
    `postings`.`id`, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(postings.post_date) as post_date, 
    `postings`.`link`, 
    `postings`.`title`, 
    `postings`.`author`, 
    `postings`.`excerpt`, 
    `postings`.`long_excerpt`, 
    `feeds`.`title` AS feed_title, 
    `feeds`.`website` AS feed_website
FROM 
    `postings` FORCE INDEX (ix_active_offtopic)
JOIN 
    `feeds` 
ON 
    `feeds`.`id` = `postings`.`feed_id`
WHERE 
    `feeds`.`type` = 1 AND 
    `postings`.`user_offtopic_count` < 10 AND 
    `postings`.`is_active` = 1
ORDER BY 
    `postings`.`post_date` desc
LIMIT 
    15

/* This should show RANGE access with few rows and keep the FILESORT */

SELECT 
    `postings`.`id`, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(postings.post_date) as post_date, 
    `postings`.`link`, 
    `postings`.`title`, 
    `postings`.`author`, 
    `postings`.`excerpt`, 
    `postings`.`long_excerpt`, 
    `feeds`.`title` AS feed_title, 
    `feeds`.`website` AS feed_website
FROM 
    `postings` FORCE INDEX (ix_active_date)
JOIN 
    `feeds` 
ON 
    `feeds`.`id` = `postings`.`feed_id`
WHERE 
    `feeds`.`type` = 1 AND 
    `postings`.`user_offtopic_count` < 10 AND 
    `postings`.`is_active` = 1
ORDER BY 
    `postings`.`post_date` desc
LIMIT 
    15

/* This should show REF access with lots of rows and no FILESORT */
```

Comment: That did the trick for me, thanks a lot! I had to use force index to get the best index used. We are now using multiple combined indexes for the different queries.

Comment: Works like a charm, the force index is really where it's at, when adding subqueries, the optimizer seems to throw things down the drain.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has two filesort algorithms: an older filesort that sorts records on disk, and a new version that works in memory.

If it cannot use an index on the first table in the join to sort the query, it will have to do a filesort. If resultset before sorting converted to fixed-width format is greater than the sort buffer *OR* if it contains any text fields, it will have to use the slower on-disk filesort algorithm (the second condition is satisfied since your query has a text field).

MySQL is choosing to use the is_active column, ostensibly because it thinks that column is most selective in eliminating rows before it continues with the other joins and where conditions. The first thing I would suggest would be to try creating composite indexes with post_date, feed_id, and the columns in the where condition, e.g. (is_active, user_offtopic_count, post_date, feed_id).

Answer (score 3):

Also, it's important to remember that MySQL won't use an index if the column you're ordering by has a function applied to it.

You should also try aliasing postings.post_date as something else.  This will tell MySQL to order by the unaltered column, and you'll still select the unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

[using in MySQL v8] **I found the order of columns in a composite index to make a huge difference when using an ORDER BY clause.** The query was using a composite index on columns `SurveyId,IgnoreResponse,EndDate` (in that order) and was returning query times of more than **1.5 seconds**.

```
SELECT JsonResponseV3, SurveyId
FROM survey
WHERE (
    (IgnoreResponse=0 OR IgnoreResponse IS NULL)
    AND
    (SurveyId = 'SV_xy3')
)
ORDER BY EndDate ASC LIMIT 25 -- where EndDate is a date time field
```

After altering the index (as shown below in the screenshot from MySQL WorkBench) and moving `EndDate` the first indexed column (`EndDate,SurveyId,IgnoreResponse`) the query time dropped to **0.016 seconds**.

[image]

(Note: if I reverted the index back to having `EndDate` be the last indexed column, the query times went back to 1.5+ seconds)