# Slow query when using ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Here's the query (the largest table has about 40,000 rows)

```
SELECT
  Course.CourseID,
  Course.Description,
  UserCourse.UserID,
  UserCourse.TimeAllowed,
  UserCourse.CreatedOn,
  UserCourse.PassedOn,
  UserCourse.IssuedOn,
  C.LessonCnt
FROM
  UserCourse
INNER JOIN
  Course
USING(CourseID)
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT CourseID, COUNT(*) AS LessonCnt FROM CourseSection GROUP BY CourseID
) C
USING(CourseID)
WHERE 
  UserCourse.UserID = 8810
```

If I run this, it executes very quickly (.05 seconds roughly). It returns 13 rows.

**When I add an `ORDER BY` clause at the end of the query (ordering by any column) the query takes about 10 seconds.**

I'm using this database in production now, and everything is working fine. All my other queries are speedy.

Any ideas of what it could be? I ran the query in MySQL's Query Browser, and from the command line. Both places it was dead slow with the `ORDER BY`.

**EDIT:** Tolgahan ALBAYRAK solution works, but can anyone explain why it works?

Comment: Why it works? a sub-query takes the result in a result set, and ordering a result-set is much faster than having the default query execution have count in ordering along the way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

maybe this helps:

```
SELECT * FROM (    
     SELECT
      Course.CourseID,
      Course.Description,
      UserCourse.UserID,
      UserCourse.TimeAllowed,
      UserCourse.CreatedOn,
      UserCourse.PassedOn,
      UserCourse.IssuedOn,
      C.LessonCnt
    FROM
      UserCourse
    INNER JOIN
      Course
    USING(CourseID)
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT CourseID, COUNT(*) AS LessonCnt FROM CourseSection GROUP BY CourseID
    ) C
    USING(CourseID)
    WHERE 
      UserCourse.UserID = 8810
) ORDER BY CourseID
```

Comment: Huh, that works (makes it execute fast). Do you know why though? I've never had to do that before.

Comment: 40k isnt that many records; typically have to deal with millions soyour  milage may vary but this may help improve the performance further on this as the joins will be done on a reduced dataset.
...
FROM
      (Select * from UserCourse
Where UserID = 8810
) UserCourse

Comment: tvanfosson, I always thought the ORDER BY was processed after the results were returned. I guess that isn't necessarily the case. I'll have to investigate a bit more. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Is the column you're ordering by indexed?

Indexing drastically speeds up ordering and filtering.

Comment: the op mentioned using any column in the order by reduces performance

Comment: Any column, including the indexed columns, make it run slow.

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting from "**UserCourse**" which I assume is a joining table between courses and users (Many to Many).
You should index the column that you need to order by, in the "UserCourse" table.

Suppose you want to "**order by CourseID**", then you need to index it on *UserCourse* table.

Ordering by any other column that is not present in the joining table (i.e. UserCourse) may require further denormalization and indexing *on the joining table* to be optimized for speed;
In other words, you need to have a copy of that column in the joining table and index it.

**P.S.**
The answer given by Tolgahan Albayrak, although correct for this question, would not produce the desired result, in cases where one is doing a  "LIMIT x" query.

Answer (score 2):

Have you updated the statistics on your database?  I ran into something similar on mine where I had 2 identical queries where the only difference was a capital letter and one returned in 1/2 a second and the other took nearly 5 minutes.  Updating the statistics resolved the issue

Comment: Bizarre, I just ran into a similar issue and updating the statistics did fix this. We had to restore a database backup for this environment a couple days ago which probably caused this in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Realise answer is too late, however I have just had a similar problem, adding order by increased the query time from seconds to 5 minutes and having tried most other suggestions for speeding it up, noticed that the /tmp files where getting to be 12G for this query.  Changed the query such that a varchar(20000) field being returned was "trim("ed and performance dramatically improved (back to seconds).  So I guess its worth checking whether you are returning large varchars as part of your query and if so, process them (maybe substring(x, 1, length(x))?? if you dont want to trim them.
Query was returning 500k rows and the /tmp file indicated that each row was using about 20k of data.

Answer (score 1):

Today I was running into a same kind of problem. As soon as I was sorting the resultset by a field from a joined table, the whole query was horribly slow and took more than a hundred seconds.

The server was running MySQL 5.0.51a and by chance I noticed that the same query was running as fast as it should have always done on a server with MySQL 5.1. When comparing the explains for that query I saw that obviously the usage and handling of indexes has changed a lot (at least from 5.0 -> 5.1).

So if you encounter such a problem, maybe your resolution is to simply upgrade your MySQL

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked before [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714950/mysql-performance-optimization-order-by-datetime-field)

It might help you as well.  Basically it describes using composite indexes and how order by works.