# ORDER BY making MySQL query run very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
   table1.*, table2.*    
FROM 
   `Table1` AS table1, 
   `Table2` AS table2, 
   `Table3` 
WHERE 
   table1.col1 = table2.col1 AND
   table1.col1 = Table3.col1 AND  
   table1.col1 != '0' AND 
   table1.col1 NOT IN (1,2) 
   table1.col2 LIKE 'A' AND 
   (table1.col3 LIKE 'A' OR table1.col3 LIKE 'B') AND 
   Table3.col4 = 0 AND 
   Table3.col5 = 0 AND 
   Table3.col6 = 0 
ORDER BY 
   table1.col10 ASC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Without the ORDER BY statement, it executes in 0.002 seconds.

With the ORDER BY statement, it executes in 2 seconds.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884661/slow-query-when-using-order-by) which seemed to work for the OP, but when I tried it on mine I got a `Duplicate column name 'col1'` error.

Any ideas on how I can speed this up with the ORDER BY ?

**EDIT:**

As requested, below is the modified Query that I tried based on the link above which gave me the `Duplicate column name 'col1'` error:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
       table1.*, table2.*    
    FROM 
       `Table1` AS table1, 
       `Table2` AS table2, 
       `Table3` 
    WHERE 
       table1.col1 = table2.col1 AND
       table1.col1 = Table3.col1 AND  
       table1.col1 != '0' AND 
       table1.col1 NOT IN (1,2) 
       table1.col2 LIKE 'A' AND 
       (table1.col3 LIKE 'A' OR table1.col3 LIKE 'B') AND 
       Table3.col4 = 0 AND 
       Table3.col5 = 0 AND 
       Table3.col6 = 0 
) AS t1
ORDER BY 
   table1.col10 ASC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Apparently, this is supposed to ensure the ORDER BY is only done after the final result set is determined.

Comment: This query as it stands won't work. You might want to edit the question. General advice for speeding up queries: ensure you have the correct indexes and don't `select *` if you don't need all that data. The less you return the less work has to be done. If you got a duplicate column name error that's because you've probably got a duplicate column name give one of your columns with the same name an alias ( another reason not to use `*` ).

Comment: Your query won't run. "Table3.col6 = 0 AND" the "AND" part is missing.

Comment: Can you post the modified query which you tried as well?

Comment: Try to take a look at: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/25/impact-of-the-sort-buffer-size-in-mysql/

Comment: @Programmer That will happen because `col1` exists in both tables and you're not differentiating between the two. Try explicitly selecting all the columns you need for `table1` and `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an index on `table1` and `col10` .

Comment: They already have an index.  This query runs very fast without the ORDER BY, but when I add it, it makes it run too slow. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can also explore to use temp table

```
SELECT
   table1.*, table2.* INTO #temp
FROM 
   `Table1` AS table1, 
   `Table2` AS table2, 
   `Table3` 
WHERE 
   table1.col1 = table2.col1 AND
   table1.col1 = Table3.col1 AND  
   table1.col1 != '0' AND 
   table1.col1 NOT IN (1,2) 
   table1.col2 LIKE 'A' AND 
   (table1.col3 LIKE 'A' OR table1.col3 LIKE 'B') AND 
   Table3.col4 = 0 AND 
   Table3.col5 = 0 AND 
   Table3.col6 = 0 

SELECT * FROM #temp  
ORDER BY col10 ASC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```