# SQL Server join query slow when using order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, sql-order-by

There are 2 tables in our database.

1. `U_Accounts` (small table containing rows)
2. `SMS_Buffer` (big table containing SMS queue)

Below is the sample query

```
Select SMS_Buffer.msg_id, 
       SMS_Buffer.u_id, 
       SMS_Buffer.msgtxt, 
       SMS_Buffer.m_priority, 
       U_Accounts.U_Priority 
From SMS_Buffer
JOIN U_Accounts ON Sms_Buffer.u_id = U_Accounts.u_id 
where U_Accounts.u_msgpush=1 
Order by U_Accounts.u_priority DESC, 
         SMS_Buffer.m_priority DESC, 
         SMS_Buffer.m_id DESC
```

Above query becomes slow when we use `ORDER BY` clause with `SMS_Buffer.m_priority DESC, SMS_Buffer.m_id DESC` for records less then 100000 rows in `SMS_Buffer` table but when it grows query becomes very slow.

Request you to provide us a solution for better performance of the above query.

We have tried creating clustered, non-clustered indexes but did not got any success.

Comment: please format your code next time, it's very hard to read a wall of text

Comment: what indexes did you create and what is your execution plan?

Comment: And define slow, and what keys you have...

Comment: please provide schema, please take out ORDER BY and try again, still slow?

Comment: Not even a guess without seeing an execution plan.

Comment: Rebuild your indexes and table statistics.  (shot in the dark, eh)

Answer (score 1):

This can't be answered properly without further information as to indexes and ideally an execution plan, but the behaviour you see, whereby a fast query with a relatively small number of rows sees performance deteriorate rapidly when it reaches a certain volume is usually indicative of a query using a full table scan, which isn't too bad when the table fits in memory but deteriorates catastrophically when it grows so large that data is written to disk (disk I/O is orders of magnitude slower than operations in memory so the point at which you hit this is often noticable).

Your only way to tackle this is to examine the execution plan and determine what is causing the full scan, but without that essential information you are trying to solve this blind.

Comment: Your best bet would be to reference the execution plan - that would be the best - [link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into the same sort of thing Fry's answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884661/slow-query-when-using-order-by/884681#884681) helped.  In short Update Statistics may be the solution.  In SQL **EXEC sp_updatestats**.

I was dealing with 2 sub-queries and a table, then sorting.  The 3 result sets were under 5,000 rows and adding the Order By would take it from 12 seconds to 5 minutes.  It was ridiculously slow.  After updating statistics it ran in 1 second.