# MySQL very slow with OrderBy

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I've been having an issue with one of my queries running very slowly when OrderBy has been applied.

I've already taken a look around and surrounded my query with a SELECT * FROM (sql stuff) OrderBy field. This decreased the time from 22 seconds to 10 seconds, but I really need to get it quicker. The SQL_NO_CACHE was just for testing.

This returns 5866 records in 10 seconds. Removing the orderby returns in 2 seconds.

```
SELECT 
     SQL_NO_CACHE * 
FROM
     (SELECT 
          SUM(
               MATCH(product_name) 
               AGAINST ('"Jeans"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) + 
               MATCH(store_name) 
               AGAINST ('"Jeans"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
          ) AS searchScore,
          product_name,
          section_url,
          product_link_url,
          affiliate_store_product_id,
          store_url,
          product_date_added,
          product_image,
          product_image_path,
          product_sale_price,
          product_price,
          product_price_currency,
          product_url,
          product_id,
          product_channel_id,
          store_name,
          product_brand,
          colour_id,
          colour_name 
     FROM
          products 
          INNER JOIN stores 
               ON store_id = product_store_id 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN product_colours 
               ON product_colour_product_id = product_id 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN colours 
               ON colour_id = product_colour_colour_id 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN sections 
               ON product_channel_id = section_id 
          INNER JOIN storeShipping 
               ON storeShipping_store_id = store_id 
          INNER JOIN shipping_locations 
               ON shipping_location_id = storeShipping_shipping_location_id 
          JOIN product_categories 
               ON product_category_product_id = product_id 
          JOIN categories 
               ON category_id = product_category_category_id 
     WHERE (
               MATCH(product_name) AGAINST ('"Jeans"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
               OR MATCH(store_name) AGAINST ('"Jeans"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
          ) 
          AND product_status = 1 
          AND category_status = 1 
          AND product_excluded = 0 
          AND product_feed_status = 1 
          AND store_status = 1 
          AND shipping_location_currency_code = 'AUD' 
          AND product_image_path IS NOT NULL 
          AND (
               product_channel_id = 1 
               OR product_channel_id = 2 
               OR product_channel_id = 3 
               OR product_channel_id = 4
          ) 
     GROUP BY product_url) AS T 
ORDER BY searchScore DESC ;
```

Here is the explain for the orderby

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |       table        |  type  |                                                       possible_keys                                                       |          key           | key_len |                       ref                        |  rows  |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>         | ALL    | \N                                                                                                                        | \N                     | \N      | \N                                               |   5866 | Using filesort                               |
|  2 | DERIVED     | products           | ref    | PRIMARY,idx_product,idx_channel,idx_path,idx_store,idx_excluded,idx_status,idx_product_feed_status,idx_product_image_path | idx_status             | 2       |                                                  | 306688 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | stores             | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_storestatus                                                                                                   | PRIMARY                | 4       | products.product_store_id                        |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | product_categories | ref    | PRIMARY,idx_category,idx_categoryproduct                                                                                  | idx_categoryproduct    | 4       | products.product_id                              |      1 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | categories         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,NewIndex1                                                                                                         | PRIMARY                | 4       | product_categories.product_category_category_id  |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | product_colours    | ref    | idx_colourproduct                                                                                                         | idx_colourproduct      | 5       | products.product_id                              |      2 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | colours            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                   | PRIMARY                | 4       | product_colours.product_colour_colour_id         |      1 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | storeShipping      | ref    | idx_storeshippingstore,idx_storeshippinglocation                                                                          | idx_storeshippingstore | 5       | stores.store_id                                  |      4 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | shipping_locations | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_shippinglocation                                                                                              | PRIMARY                | 4       | storeShipping.storeShipping_shipping_location_id |      1 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | sections           | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                   | PRIMARY                | 4       | products.product_channel_id                      |      1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

And without the orderby

```
+--------+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|     id | select_type |       table        |  type  |                                                       possible_keys                                                       |          key           | key_len |                       ref                        |  rows  |                    Extra                     |
+--------+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|      1 | SIMPLE      | products           | ref    | PRIMARY,idx_product,idx_channel,idx_path,idx_store,idx_excluded,idx_status,idx_product_feed_status,idx_product_image_path | idx_status             |       2 | const                                            | 306688 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|      1 | SIMPLE      | stores             | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_storestatus                                                                                                   | PRIMARY                |       4 | products.product_store_id                        |      1 | Using where                                  |
|      1 | SIMPLE      | product_categories | ref    | PRIMARY,idx_category,idx_categoryproduct                                                                                  | idx_categoryproduct    |       4 | products.product_id                              |      1 |                                              |
|      1 | SIMPLE      | categories         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,NewIndex1                                                                                                         | PRIMARY                |       4 | product_categories.product_category_category_id  |      1 | Using where                                  |
|      1 | SIMPLE      | product_colours    | ref    | idx_colourproduct                                                                                                         | idx_colourproduct      |       5 | products.product_id                              |      2 |                                              |
|      1 | SIMPLE      | colours            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                   | PRIMARY                |       4 | product_colours.product_colour_colour_id         |      1 |                                              |
|      1 | SIMPLE      | storeShipping      | ref    | idx_storeshippingstore,idx_storeshippinglocation                                                                          | idx_storeshippingstore |       5 | stores.store_id                                  |      4 | Using where                                  |
|      1 | SIMPLE      | shipping_locations | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_shippinglocation                                                                                              | PRIMARY                |       4 | storeShipping.storeShipping_shipping_location_id |      1 | Using where                                  |
|      1 | SIMPLE      | sections           | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                   | PRIMARY                |       4 | products.product_channel_id                      |      1 |                                              |
+--------+-------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Anything you guys can do to give me a boost would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing the `ORDER BY` in a parent query and not just applying an `ORDER BY` clause to the subquery?  Your query is needlessly sorting the results twice (once for the grouping operation, and again for the ordering operation).

Comment: I don't think I understand where you're coming from, I've formatted the way I have with the orderby from this advice. Which has helped in several over queries, it's also helped this one to a point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884661/slow-query-when-using-order-by

Comment: I tried running the edited version of my query you posted, but it's still taking 10 seconds to return.

Comment: The edited version that who posted?  I haven't posted any edit to your query (I only tidied up the `EXPLAIN` output tables).  Perhaps you intended that comment for one of the answers below?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that chap. Me misreading it.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your query a little. Can you try it?
Also please `INDEX` the column `product_url` this will improve the execution a lot. 
Also if possible `INDEX` the columns `product_name` and `store_name`.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN product_name LIKE '%Jeans%' OR store_name LIKE '%Jeans%' 
                THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 END) AS searchScore,
       product_name, 
       section_url, 
       product_link_url, 
       affiliate_store_product_id, 
       store_url, 
       product_date_added, 
       product_image, 
       product_image_path, 
       product_sale_price, 
       product_price, 
       product_price_currency, 
       product_url, 
       product_id, 
       product_channel_id, 
       store_name, 
       product_brand, 
       colour_id, 
       colour_name 
FROM products 
             INNER JOIN stores ON store_id = product_store_id 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN product_colours ON product_colour_product_id = product_id 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN colours ON colour_id = product_colour_colour_id 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN sections ON product_channel_id = section_id 
             INNER JOIN storeShipping ON storeShipping_store_id = store_id 
             INNER JOIN shipping_locations ON shipping_location_id = storeShipping_shipping_location_id 
             JOIN product_categories ON product_category_product_id = product_id 
             JOIN categories ON category_id = product_category_category_id 
WHERE (product_name LIKE '%Jeans%' OR store_name LIKE '%Jeans%')
AND product_status = 1 
AND category_status = 1 
AND product_excluded = 0 
AND product_feed_status = 1 
AND store_status = 1 
AND shipping_location_currency_code = 'AUD' 
AND product_image_path IS NOT NULL 
AND product_channel_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4) 
GROUP BY product_url
ORDER BY searchScore
```

Comment: Running this returned 0 results. Also from what I can see, there is no orderby?

Comment: There is no MATCH AGAINST, its replaced by `=`, therefore it doesnt work. Put in there `LIKE` instead of `=` and surround text by `%`. Then it should work

Comment: Well it does work, but with a 17 second return time, so it's slower than my original query.

Answer (score 0):

You're ordering by `searchScore`, which is not table field, but some dynamically aggregated value. Therefore MySQL can't use indexes for sorting and uses FileSort instead. This is of course slow.

Now, regarding optimization tips:

1. If your `product_url`, `product_name`, `store_name` are not greater than 255 chars  - then use VARCHAR(255) or even CHAR(255) for them. And ensure that `product_url` is indexed field (not full text index, but normal index). Actually, all 3 fields have to be indexed.
2. Are you sure you need to use `MATCH AGAINST` construction? It would work faster if you'd use `REGEXP` there, but I dont know exact requirements.
3. Its again related to p.1 - you have fields as (VAR)CHAR(255) - then add composite index of all the fields in `WHERE` + `GROUP BY`, I mean: product_name, store_name, product_status, category_status, product_excluded, product_feed_status, store_status, shipping_location_currency_mode, product_image_path, product_channel_id, product_url. Plus, you haev to have `product_url` as a separate index.

Hope it will help. After my proposed modifications you should have this query executed in less than one second.

Comment: I've already got all my fields that need it set to varchar(255), I've also get the indexes set up best I can. I just added a single index with the fields from the products table you suggested. Am I right in thinking I can't index fields from separate tables into one index? I am now looking at using REGEXP but so far no speed increase.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that those fields are from different tables. Of course you cant grab them into one index, but need to group them at least table wise... I'd like to play with this query. Any chance you can upload a dump somewhere (with fake values)?