# How to optimize MySQL "Order By Limit 1" in queries that join multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, sql-order-by, sql-limit

So I have a query like this:

```
SELECT tablea.name, tablea.views from tablea inner 
join tableb on (tablea.id = tableb.id and tablea.balance > 0) 
order by tablea.views asc limit 1
```

However, the problem is that when I run it, it runs quite slow (4+ seconds).
Interestingly, when the 'order by' clause is removed, while keeping the limit 1, it runs in 0.005 seconds (approx).

Even more interestingly: when I don't join it to tableb, i.e.:

```
SELECT tablea.name, tablea.views from tablea 
where tablea.balance > 0 
order by tablea.views asc limit 1
```

The query runs in 0.005 seconds usually.

Notes:

- The column views in tablea is indexed
- tablea and tableb have a 1 to 1 relationship in terms of id, and roughly have the same amount of rows.

Why is there such a drastic difference in performance between the first query, the first query when 'order by' is removed, and the second query?

Would there anyway to make the sorting much faster when joining two tables?

Comment: Can you run `EXPLAIN` on the original join query?  Let's see what is actually happening there.

Comment: Questions about performance always require CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well as the result of the EXPLAIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible explanation as to what is going on here is that MySQL is choosing to do the ordering *before* it does the actual join.  As you saw in your original query when removing the `ORDER BY` clause, the joining by itself is not a performance problem.  One way to get around this would be to wrap your original query in a subquery, and then order it:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT tablea.name,
           tablea.views
    FROM tablea
    INNER JOIN tableb
        ON tablea.id = tableb.id AND
           tablea.balance > 0
) t
ORDER BY t.views ASC
LIMIT 1
```

If this works, then it probably confirms what I speculated.  In this case, the subquery forces MySQL to only order records which result from the actual subquery.  In any case, you should get in the habit of running `EXPLAIN` on such queries.  My guess is that the index isn't being used/effective when joining in your original query.

**Reference:** [Slow query when using ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884661/slow-query-when-using-order-by)

Answer (score 0):

```
Given INDEX(x)
ORDER BY x LIMIT 1
```

Will conveniently use the index and pick off the first item

```
Given INDEX(x)
WHERE ...
ORDER BY x LIMIT 1
```

May also use the index, and *hope* that some early row is satisfied by the `WHERE`.  If not, then it could have to scan the entire table to find the one row !

```
Given INDEX(a, x)
WHERE a = 12
ORDER BY x LIMIT 1
```

No problem -- Look in the index for a=12; pick the first item.

```
Given INDEX(a, x)
WHERE a > 12
ORDER BY x LIMIT 1
```

Now the index is not so good.  It will need to pick up all the rows with a>12, sort by x, then deliver one row.

In general, *if* the `WHERE`, and `ORDER BY` can be completely satisfied, then `LIMIT n` can be optimized.  (This assumes no `GROUP BY`, or the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are *identical*.)

That's with one table.  When you `JOIN` two (or more) tables, it gets messier.  With two tables, the Optimizer chooses one table, finds what it can there, then does a Nested Loop Join to the other table.

Usually (not always), a `WHERE` clause (on one table) tells the Optimizer "pick me".  If that's the same table as the `ORDER BY`, then the above discussion may kick in.

Without a `WHERE` clause, the Optimizer usually starts with the smaller table.  (Note:  The table size is based on row *estimates* and may not be correct every time.)

Your first query might be sped up by using `WHERE EXISTS ( ... tableb ... )` instead of the `JOIN tableb...`.  The Optimizer would see that as something worth optimizing.

Etc, etc, etc.

Note that your "0.005 seconds" was "luck".

If you want to dig deeper, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (so we can see the index(es), etc), `EXPLAIN SELECT` (so we can discuss what the Optimizer decided on) and, if possible `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for more details.  Also see [*my indexing cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) .