# Optimizing Left Join With Group By and Order By (MariaDb)

Tags: performance, mariadb, sql-order-by

I am attempting to optimize a query in MariaDb that is really bogged down by its ORDER BY clause. I can run it in under a tenth of a second without the ORDER BY clause, but it takes over 25 seconds with it. Here is the gist of the query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.display_name, u.cell_phone, u.email, 
uv.year, uv.make, uv.model, uv.id AS user_vehicle_id
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN user_vehicles uv ON uv.user_id = u.id AND uv.current_owner=1
WHERE u.is_deleted = 0
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.display_name 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

- I need it to be a left join because I want to include users that aren't linked to a vehicle.
- I need the group by because I want only 1 result per user (and display_name is not guaranteed to be unique).
- users table has about 130K rows, while user_vehicles has about 230K rows.

Here is the EXPLAIN of the query:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key      key_len  ref           rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      u       index   dms_cust_idx    PRIMARY  4        null          124825  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      uv      ref     user_idx        user_idx 4        awscheduler.u.id  1   Using where
```

I have tried these two indices to speed things up, but they don't seem to do much.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_display_speedy ON users(display_name);

CREATE INDEX idx_display_speedy2 ON users(id, display_name, is_deleted, dms_cust_id);
```

I am looking for ideas on how to speed this up. I attempted using nested queries, but since the order by is the bottleneck & order within the nested query is ignored, I believe that attempt was in vain.

Comment: There is a trick to order results after the query. The answer already exists, please check [Slow query when using order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884661/slow-query-when-using-order-by#answer-884678).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
WITH a AS (
   SELECT u.id, u.display_name, u.cell_phone, u.email
   FROM users u 
   WHERE u.is_deleted = 0
   GROUP BY u.id
   LIMIT 0, 10
) 
SELECT a.id, a.display_name, a.cell_phone, a.email, 
       uv.year, uv.make, uv.model, uv.id AS user_vehicle_id
FROM a LEFT JOIN user_vehicles uv ON uv.user_id = a.id AND uv.current_owner=1
ORDER BY a.display_name;
```

The intention is we take a subset of users before joining it with `user_vehicles`.
Disclaimer: I haven't verified if its faster or not, but have similar experience in the past where this helps.

Comment: The only thing I had to change was moving the order by clause into the subquery. Still very performant, much appreciated.

Comment: so it is indeed faster, nice, thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 0):

```
with a as (
   SELECT u.id, u.display_name, u.cell_phone, u.email, 
   uv.year, uv.make, uv.model, uv.id AS user_vehicle_id
   FROM users u 
   LEFT JOIN user_vehicles uv ON uv.user_id = u.id AND uv.current_owner=1
   WHERE u.is_deleted = 0
   GROUP BY u.id
) 
select * from a
ORDER BY u.display_name; 



)
```

Comment: I ran this after changing the ORDER BY to 'ORDER BY a.display_name' and it did not speed things up significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's not actually the ordering that is causing the problem...  If you remove the limit, I bet the ordered and un-ordered versions will end up performing pretty close to the same.

Depending on if your actual query is as simple as the one you posted, you *may* be able to get good performance in a single query by using RowNum() as [described here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rownum/):

```
SELECT u.id, u.display_name, u.cell_phone, u.email, 
uv.year, uv.make, uv.model, uv.id AS user_vehicle_id
FROM (
    SELECT iu.id, iu.display_name, iu.cell_phone, iu.email
    FROM users iu 
    WHERE iu.is_deleted = 0
    ORDER BY iu.display_name) as u
LEFT JOIN user_vehicles uv ON uv.user_id = u.id AND uv.current_owner=1
WHERE ROWNUM() < 10
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.display_name
```

If that doesn't work, you probably need to select the users in one select and then select their vehicles in a second Select

Comment: Even without the limit, the query was very slow.