# Why is MySQL select count(*) so slow on fast subquery?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following query that executes quite fast:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.products_id, 
                p.products_image, 
                p.products_quantity, 
                p.products_status, 
                m.manufacturers_id, 
                p.products_date_added, 
                p.products_subimage1, 
                pd.products_name, 
                p.products_price, 
                p.products_length, 
                p.products_width, 
                p.products_height, 
                p.products_tax_class_id, 
                IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL)             AS 
                specials_new_products_price, 
                IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) AS 
                final_price,
                IF(clearance_price < products_cost * 2.25, 
                clearance_price, 
                products_cost * 2.25)                                       AS 
                sorting_price 

FROM   

       (SELECT products_id ,
                IF(clearance_price < products_cost * 2.25, 
                clearance_price, 
                products_cost * 2.25)                                       AS 
                sorting_price 
                FROM `products` 
                ORDER BY products_id DESC)q,


       products p
       left join manufacturers m USING(manufacturers_id) 
       left join specials s 
              ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
       left join products_attributes pa 
              ON p.products_id = pa.products_id 
       left join products_options po 
              ON pa.options_id = po.products_options_id 
       left join products_options_values pov 
              ON pa.options_values_id = pov.products_options_values_id, 
       products_description pd, 
       categories c, 
       products_to_categories p2c 
WHERE  

       q.products_id = p.products_id 
       AND q.sorting_price = sorting_price
       AND 

       p.products_status = '1' 
       AND p.products_id = pd.products_id 
       AND pd.language_id = '1' 
       AND p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
       AND p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id 
       AND (( pd.products_name LIKE '%a%' 
               OR po.products_options_name LIKE '%a%' 
               OR pov.products_options_values_name LIKE '%a%' 
               OR pd.products_description LIKE '%a%' ))
```

When I wrap it inside a count(*) query, the new count query takes 10 to 15 times more time, very slow.
I wrap it like so:

```
SELECT count(*) as total from (
    SELECT DISTINCT p.products_id, 
                p.products_image, 
                p.products_quantity, 
                p.products_status, 
                m.manufacturers_id, 
                p.products_date_added, 
                p.products_subimage1, 
                pd.products_name, 
                p.products_price, 
                p.products_length, 
                p.products_width, 
                p.products_height, 
                p.products_tax_class_id, 
                IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL)             AS 
                specials_new_products_price, 
                IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) AS 
                final_price,
                IF(clearance_price < products_cost * 2.25, 
                clearance_price, 
                products_cost * 2.25)                                       AS 
                sorting_price 

FROM   

       (SELECT products_id ,
                IF(clearance_price < products_cost * 2.25, 
                clearance_price, 
                products_cost * 2.25)                                       AS 
                sorting_price 
                FROM `products` 
                ORDER BY products_id DESC)q,


       products p
       left join manufacturers m USING(manufacturers_id) 
       left join specials s 
              ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
       left join products_attributes pa 
              ON p.products_id = pa.products_id 
       left join products_options po 
              ON pa.options_id = po.products_options_id 
       left join products_options_values pov 
              ON pa.options_values_id = pov.products_options_values_id, 
       products_description pd, 
       categories c, 
       products_to_categories p2c 
WHERE  

       q.products_id = p.products_id 
       AND q.sorting_price = sorting_price
       AND 

       p.products_status = '1' 
       AND p.products_id = pd.products_id 
       AND pd.language_id = '1' 
       AND p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
       AND p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id 
       AND (( pd.products_name LIKE '%a%' 
               OR po.products_options_name LIKE '%a%' 
               OR pov.products_options_values_name LIKE '%a%' 
               OR pd.products_description LIKE '%a%' ))
    ) AS derivedtable1
```

Why does this happen? Is there any way to optimize this?

**EDIT:**
This is the EXPLAIN EXTENDED of the first query:
[image]

This is the EXPLAIN EXTENDED of the count (the second) query:
[image]

This is the PROFILING of the first query:
[image]

This is the PROFILING of the count (the second) query:
[image]

Comment: you're counting lots of `distinct`s,

Comment: Why aren't you doing SELECT count(DISTINCT ... ?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I tried with `SELECT count(DISTINCT products_id)`, performance is the same

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each of the two.

Comment: Instead of `a,b ... WHERE a.x=b.y`, write `a JOIN b ON a.x=b.y`.  (I'm having trouble following your code.)

Comment: @RickJames edited my question with the `EXPLAIN`s as requested

Comment: @RickJames edited again, added the profiling if that helps tracking down the cause and solution. The screenshot also shows the execution time of the first query. The count query in this case takes  around1.5s (10 times longer)

Comment: Have you considered ***using the first query*** and simply ***using the number of rows returned.*** The combination of subquery and multiple joins will slow down your search, especially in a large database.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @JonathanCrowe I think I didn't, but can't really recall as it was years ago. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM pd
LEFT JOIN po ON ...
WHERE ( ... OR po.x LIKE '...' OR ... )
```

The semantics of `LEFT` say that it does not matter whether there is a matching row in `po`.  Hence the `LIKE` has zero impact on the outcome of the query.  Suggest you get rid of `OR ... LIKE` of any items in `LEFT`.  Or maybe you did not really mean LEFT?  That *could* make it run faster, but the result set *could* be different.

I see from the `EXPLAINs` that there is no good excuse for the difference in timing.  Oh, how are you running the queries?  The first one has 213K rows of output -- are you waiting for all of it to come back before stopping your stopwatch?